# Using infinitesimals in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative, infinitesimals

In ordinary calculus,if we don't make any absurd notation,the use of infinitesimals is extremely useful and intuitive which ended up giving correct results. For example $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ are obvious if we treat $dy,dx,dt$ as infinitesimals. Can we do the same in case of multivariable calculus? For example if $V$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and $x,y$ are both functions of $r,\theta$,can we still do stuffs like $\frac{\delta V}{\delta x}=\frac{\frac{\delta V}{\delta \theta}}{\frac{\delta x}{\delta \theta}}$? Or are there scenarios where such use of infinitesimals lead to incorrect results?

Comment: Google queries with "infinitesimals" and "pitfalls" will give you answers like this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/828920/305862).

Comment: 1. If you're asking it it's possible to use infinitesimals for multivariable, just combine "Elemetary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach" with a multivariable text; I'd be happy to expand a bit on that in an answer. 2. If you're asking when a partial derivative can be treated like a fraction, that's close to [this question about reciprocals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4125401/26369). 3. If you're asking some third thing (e.g. "how to think about the multivlariable chain rule intuitively through the lens of infinitesimals"), could you rephrase your question to clarify?

Comment: @MarkS.,the link you provided answered my previous question and that led to a bit more questions of mine. Would you be available to discuss those in this chatroom? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149603/calc-problems

Comment: Not a question on infinitesimals again! Take $V(x,y)$ and apply the chain rule. Then treat  whatever infinitesimal pops up as a fraction. Further hints: non standard analysis or differential forms.

Comment: @MarkS.,the question I have is if $z$ is a function of $x,y$,would $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=0$? We can discuss further in chat room.

Comment: @JeanMarie, the pitfalls are common to the non-infinitesimal approach and the infinitesimal approach.  One certainly has to be careful with notation when working with partial derivatives.

Answer (score 6):

There are pitfalls with using notation that is too abbreviated when working in multivariate calculus, whether or not one uses infinitesimals.  Partial derivatives are treated carefully in Keisler's textbook [Elementary calculus with infinitesimals](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Ehkeisler/calc.html).  While in single-variable calculus, it is obviously an advantage to be able to express chain rule as $\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$ as literally involving fractions, there are some subtleties here, as well.  Thus, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a bit more complicated than "the y-increment over the x-increment".  The precise justification is in terms of the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function).  This is also explained very well in Keisler.