# $ds^{2}$ as in $\frac{d^{2}a(s)}{ds^2}$ is such that $ds^{2}=(ds)^{2}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am yet to see the following disambiguated:

Is it true that $ds^{2}$ as in $\frac{d^{2}a(s)}{ds^2}$ is such that $ds^{2}=(ds)^{2}$?

This comes into play when dealing with SDE's as $(dW_{t})^{2}=dt$ which can be shown if it assumed $(dW_{t})^{2}=dW_{t}^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\dfrac{ {\rm d}^2a(s)}{{\rm d}s^2}$ is an abbreviation for $\dfrac{{\rm d}\left( \dfrac{ {\rm d} a(s) }{{\rm d} s}\right)} {{\rm d} s}$.  You can multiply out one of the ${\rm d}s$ but not the other.

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/765077/97045 and other answers in that thread for reasons why treating ${\rm d}s^2$ as a product leads to contradictions.

Comment: Interesting. Outside of the context of $\dfrac{{\rm d}\left( \dfrac{ {\rm d} a(s) }{{\rm d} s}\right)} {{\rm d} s}$, does the differential $ds^{2}=(ds)^{2}$, ever?

Comment: I tentatively would say you could do that when you are multiplying 2 first derivatives together, but to claim something never leads to a contradiction is a really heavy claim.

Comment: Perhaps then I will make a follow-up question w.r.t. the generality of it.